# Getting 404 error instead of automatically loading index.php on add-on domain

Tags: html, http-status-code-404, litespeed

Server gives a 404 error instead of serving up an index.php or index.html file on the www.domainname.com call. If I type in www.domainname.com/index.php it works fine, but not otherwise. This domain is an add-on domain to my existing cpanel installation, so I don't know if that is related. Permissions are set to execute on the file. I tried creating a .htaccess file in the directory with the following:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

This did not work. Wondering how I can troubleshoot this. Running LiteSpeed Web Server on shared hosting. What could be causing this?

Comment: Woops, should have posted to server fault.

Comment: Could be the add on domain is taking some time to propagate...  
Try putting `something.txt` there and go to yourAddonDomain.domain.com/something.txt and see if it comes up

Answer (score 0):

When I renamed .htaccess to .htaccess.bak in the parent directory, everything worked as expected. It seems there is probably an error in that .htaccess file that is propagating sub-directories as well. I will need to figure out exactly what is wrong, but that lies outside the scope of this question.

Was tipped off to the idea by: http://www.bluehostforum.com/showthread.php?38079-automatically-serve-index-html-in-subdirectories-solved